# Unable to Push Custom Framework on Cocoapods

Tags: github, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec, trunk

I have a custom framework that is already pushed on cocoaPods by some other developer and his email id is removed now. But he didn't add anyone owner of it. Now I have some changes in that framework and I want to push it on cocoaPods. Now when I am pushing it on Cocoapods from command "pod trunk push **Podspec_file_name**.podspec" it's giving me below error:-

**[!] You (my_email_address) are not allowed to push new versions for this pod. The owners of this pod are (previous_developer_Email_address)**

I tried to do it by adding the owner to me from below commands lines:-

**Command-1. pod trunk register MY_Email_Address 'My_Name'**

It sends verification links on my email address to which I have to verify by clicking.

**Command-2. pod trunk add-owner Framework_name My_email_address**

Again it's giving me error:-
**`[!] You are not allowed to add owners to this pod.`**

So I am unable to push it on cocoapods. I didn't find its solution anywhere. If anyone had faced this problem then please help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved this by recreating that old person's email-Id again. From the command line, the email verification link sent on new account and I verified that.

By the way, I was having three option to do that:-

1. **By Claiming Pods: -** I didn't take it appropriate and was not sure that I will get help from Cocoapods support because I wasn't claiming on another person's framework. I was just trying to add me as the owner for the already created pod.
2. **By Creating Another Github Repository:-** It can be resolved by shifting the current Github repository to a new one by doing some
   modification in name.
3. **Recreate account of last owner:-** I found it most appropriate to create old owner's email id with same email address which he had.
   Cocopods links went on that email and I verified that.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pod trunk info {podname}` to find the owners. Contact one of the owners to give you access.

If that doesn't work, you could try filing a claim for the pod at https://trunk.cocoapods.org/claims/new

Comment: Hi @Paul, I checked the owner from this command and found there is only one owner of that framework whose email ID is removed now. So I can't get access to it from anyone else. Is there any other way to do it other than claiming pod?

Comment: I don't think so.  That mechanism is set up to ensure the protection of established pods.

Comment: @Paurl, thanks for your help. I have resolved it. You can check it in my answer.